# Cache Storage Management - Should these be enabled?

Tags: cache

Apologies in advance if this is a silly question as I'm new to Magento. I have a feeling these should all be set to enabled but wanted to get confirmation from someone before I go ahead.

Thanks! :)

[image: Cache Storage Management]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For development installs no, for a production site absolutely yes for all of them.  It will give a relatively minor but never the less worthwhile performance boost to you store.

Note that having them enabled will mean you will have to clear your cache from time to time when doing things like editing cms/product/category content or installing new extensions.